# What is the Google Calendar webapp good for?

Tags: 14.04, webapps, calendar

After updating to 14.04.1 my Firefox suggested that I install a Google Calendar app. I did so.

As far as I can tell it is exactly the same thing as if I'd run it in Chrome. It doesn't seem to do anything different or interesting.

So, what am I missing about this? What is it good for? What makes it better than the pinned tab I've been using in Firefox?

Comment: That, along with most other webapps is plain useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zan, to be honest, it does nothing special. It's no different from the typical calender, rather when integrated in the Firefox it makes it a bit difficult to observe notes because the size of the calender is smaller than the original one. I got rid of it and now using the typical one bookmarked in my browser. Glad that I was not the only one being grumpy about it.

Cheers, Pranayy